# How to make testNG run class by class with orders of tests - testng

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng.xml, testng-annotation-test

I have a question regarding testNG.
I have five classes of tests (class a,class b,class c , class d,class e)
and in each class 3 tests (test1 test2 test3)
The problem is that I have  `@Test(groups = {"smokeTest"}, enabled = true, priority = 1)` in all tests
`@Test(groups = {"smokeTest"}, enabled = true, priority = 1)`   - class a
`@Test(groups = {"smokeTest"}, enabled = true, priority = 2)`   - class a
`@Test(groups = {"smokeTest"}, enabled = true, priority = 3)`   - class a

`@Test(groups = {"smokeTest"}, enabled = true, priority = 1)`   - class b
`@Test(groups = {"smokeTest"}, enabled = true, priority = 2)`   - class b
`@Test(groups = {"smokeTest"}, enabled = true, priority = 3)`   - class b

`@Test(groups = {"smokeTest"}, enabled = true, priority = 1)`   - class c
`@Test(groups = {"smokeTest"}, enabled = true, priority = 2)`   - class c
`@Test(groups = {"smokeTest"}, enabled = true, priority = 3)`   - class c

`@Test(groups = {"smokeTest"}, enabled = true, priority = 1)`   - class d
`@Test(groups = {"smokeTest"}, enabled = true, priority = 2)`   - class d
`@Test(groups = {"smokeTest"}, enabled = true, priority = 3)`   - class d

`@Test(groups = {"smokeTest"}, enabled = true, priority = 1)`   - class e
`@Test(groups = {"smokeTest"}, enabled = true, priority = 2)`   - class e
`@Test(groups = {"smokeTest"}, enabled = true, priority = 3)`   - class e

When I run manually class by class all is working.
However when I try to make testng do it, he is running paralleled, and jump between classes according the test's priority, and not finished the class itself.
Class a test1
class b test1  .......
If I do not want any parallelization, I want it to be executed as a human do the actions, class by class, and inside the class perform the tests as priority, How can I make testng to run this way.
this is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite allow-return-values="true" name="sanitySuite" parallel="false" thread-count="1" verbose="1" >
    <test name="smoke"  preserve-order="true" >
        <parameter name="userName" value="selmadmin@gmail.com"/>
        <parameter name="password" value="bbb"/>
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="smokeTest"/>
             </run>
        </groups>

        <packages>
            <package name =".*"/>
        </packages>
        <classes>
            <class name="tests.classA"></class>
            <class name="tests.classB"></class>
            <class name="tests.classC"></class>
            <class name="tests.classD"></class>
            <class name="tests.classE"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>

    <!--<test name="jkljlkj">-->
        <!--<packages>-->
            <!--<package name=".*"/>-->
        <!--</packages>-->
    <!--</test>-->
</suite>
```

Answer (score 0):

After adding group-by-instances="true"  and parallel="none" it solved

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">

<suite allow-return-values="true" name="sanitySuite" parallel="none" thread-count="1" verbose="1" >
    <test name="Role page"  preserve-order="true" group-by-instances="true">
        <parameter name="userName" value="selmadmin@gmail.com"/>
        <parameter name="password" value="bbb"/>
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="smokeTest"/>
             </run>
        </groups>

        <packages>
            <package name =".*"/>
        </packages>
        <classes>
            <class name="tests.classA"></class>
            <class name="tests.classB"></class>
            <class name="tests.classC"></class>
            <class name="tests.classD"></class>
            <class name="tests.classE"></class>
        </classes>
    </test>

    <!--<test name="Regression1">-->
        <!--<packages>-->
            <!--<package name=".*"/>-->
        <!--</packages>-->
    <!--</test>-->
</suite>
```